# Prove using combinatorics $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\begin{bmatrix} n \\ k \end{bmatrix} x^k = x(x+1)\dots (x+n-1)$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

This is question 1.7 (b) in the book [Combinatorial Problems and Exercises by Lovász](http://bookstore.ams.org/chel-361-h/). I have looked at the solution in the book but cannot understand the explanation given there.

Here $\begin{bmatrix} n \\ k \end{bmatrix}$ counts the number of permutations of $n$ elements with $k$ disjoint cycles.

Do someone have a simple way of showing the equivalence?

Comment: What is your definition of ${n \brack k}$? It is impossible for us to give you an insightful answer without that knowledge. One might take your identity as a *definition* of the Stirling numbers of the first kind. In such a case there is nothing to prove.

Comment: Yes, $\begin{bmatrix} n \\ k \end{bmatrix}$ indeed refers to the [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind), but I do not see the _obvious_ truth of the equality using the definition. Can you prove the identity using some combinatorial argument? A simple answer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I am just asking *which* definition you are assuming. The Stirling number of the first kind ${n\brack k}$ is $\ldots$ ?

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix} n \\ k \end{bmatrix}$ counts the number of permutations of $n$ elements with $k$ disjoint cycles. I have also added this to the question. I do not know of any other definition for this quantity. Can you also let me know other common definitions used in the literature?

Answer (score 2):

If ${n\brack k}$ is the number of elements of $S_n$ with a decomposition in $k$ disjoint cycles and we set
$$ f_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}{n\brack k}x^k \tag{1}$$
then $f_n(1) = \left| S_n\right|=n!$. If we consider an element of $S_{n+1}$ with a decomposition in $k$ disjoint cycles, there are just two cases: $n+1$ makes a cycle of length $1$ (i.e. it is a fixed point) or not. That leads to
$$ {n+1 \brack k} = n{n\brack k}+{n\brack k-1} \tag{2}$$
hence:
$$ f_{n+1}(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}{n+1\brack k}x^k = n\,f_n(x) + x\,f_n(x) = (x+n)\,f_n(x)\tag{3}$$
and the claim is a straightforward consequence of $(3)+$induction.

Comment: Thank you for the proof. But can you also give some combinatorial counting based proof, even assuming $x$ to be a positive integer, which shows that the left-hand side and the right-hand side are counting same objects.

Comment: @user1105: that is just a matter of interpretation. I showed that the LHS and RHS fulfill the same initial constraints and have the same recurrence relation, hence they are clearly counting the same objects. It is like proving that $$\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}=\sum_{n\geq 0} F_n x^n, $$ for instance.

Comment: @user1105: anyway, have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Combinatorial_proof , too.

Comment: Now I am confused. Are you using induction on $n$ or $x$? First you use $x=1$ to prove the base case for $n$ and then your inductive step involves $f_n(x)$ for any $x$. For saying that $f_n(x)$ is true, you need to show in the base case that it is true for any value of $x$.

Comment: N, obviously. The case n=1 is trivial.

Comment: Aaah, true. This was a silly question. Thanks for the clarification.